# Allow Amazon CLI only special users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

There are many users in my Amazon IAM. All of them added to admin group. May I deny used Amazon CLI for all and allow only one don't change group memberly?

Thank you.

Comment: So ou want to deny the Admin group users to use AWS CLI?

Comment: It sounds like you need to create more fine-grained groups instead of making everybody an admin.

Comment: Yes. I see this like policy. Admin can take regected this policy from console AWS. What's wrong? For example, I can deny access for any users (include administrator) to any objects in Windows or Linux (chmod 000).

Comment: Making every body admin is not a recommended best practice in AWS

Comment: I know. But there is one problem with keys. If you have access key you have access to CLI. And if change password it's not change access level by key. It's main problem.

Comment: This sounds like a culture issue, but no, you can't prevent a user with valid key from using the CLI functionality allowed by that key.  The CLI is just a wrapper making API calls, and the API endpoint has no way to know the source program making the call.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your situation is:

- Your users are authorized to have access to an Amazon EC2 instance via their EC2 Key Pairs
- The EC2 instance was launched with a Role that has been given certain permissions
- Any user who logs into the EC2 instance can therefore run [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) commands that take advantage of permissions assigned to the Role
- You do not want all users to have such permissions

If you do not want all users to have such permissions, then **you should not assigned a Role to the EC2 instance**. Instead, provide IAM credentials separately to each application on the server (although that can be a lot of effort in itself).

Another option is to allow users to use the applications (eg via an exposed port, such as a web server) but do not allow them to login to the instance.